# Nuget Dependencies not getting installed

Tags: nuget, nuget-package, nuget-server, nuspec

I am running a private Nuget Server locally on IIS.
I am creating packages and uploading them all via commadline using nuget.exe (Later on I have to put this on build server, hence the command line). However there is one issue I am stuck at.

I am trying to declare dependencies. I generate the nuspec file in the folder where the .csproj file is there. Then I manually edit the nuspec file to add this under the metadata tag:

```
<metadata>
    <dependencies>
        <group targetFramework=".NETFramework4.5">
            <dependency id="DemoProject" version="2.0.0.0" />
        </group>
   </dependencies>
</metadata>
```

DemoProject, version 2.0.0.0 is present on the Nuget Server.
The project I am creating package for, MyProj.csproj does not have the reference to the DemoProject added to it via Visual Studio. It is just at the packing time I want to create the dependency. It sounds strange but is needed for some initial validation.

Then I run pack command:

"C:\nuget\NuGet.exe" pack MyProj.csproj -IncludeReferencedProjects -Prop Configuration=Release

Then I push it to NuGet server using command line.
When I do an install via command line, then only MyProj package is present at the install location.

When I use Nuget Package Explorer and create a package, I can use the Package Dependency Editor to specify the dependency. It asks for the URL of my local Nuget Server and then adds the dependency. And when I install that package, it works !!

There seem to be no difference in the generated nuspec file in both the cases. 
Obviously Nuget Package manager is doing something which I am missing out on.

Any hints?

More details: When I create a lib folder in the Package manager console and put my dll manually, lib->net45->MyProj.dll, then when I install the package thus created also "does not" install the dependency. Back to reading documentation again.

Answer (score 0):

I know this doesn't directly answer your question but I had an issue with NuGet dependencies and my solution may possibly provide a hint.

DLL#1 was had no NuGet Dependencies.  Pushed that to my private repo.
DLL#2 referenced DLL#1 NuGet package.  Pushed that to my private repo.

All fine and dandy except from the Application project when I go to "Manage NuGet Packages...", the NuGet Package for DLL#2 is listed on the Browse tab but it shows no dependencies. I was forced to install both DLL#1 AND DLL#2 nuget packages.  I desired to install DLL#2 nuget package and get DLL#1 automatically.

The way I fixed this was uninstalling all NuGet packages from DLL#2 solution.
Then going to Tools > Options > NuGet Package Manager > General.  Then set the Default package management format to Packages.config and then unchecking the option "Allow format selection on first package install".

Then i installed all the needed NuGet packages.  Now when i pack it up and push it up to the server, it shows the proper dependencies when going to "Manage NuGet Packages...".

*nuget pack* doesn't see the dependencies because its looking for them in the *\packages folder*.  That folder didn't exist because I was using PackageReference for package management.

All worked after switching to Packages.config for package management.

I know the problem I had wasn't the same as yours but if you're not using Packages.config for package management, perhaps its related.

Answer (score 0):

Late answer but the issue with this nuspec is `<group targetFramework=".NETFramework4.5">`. I feel confident that ".NETFramework4.5" is an invalid targetFramework. A full list of the available [Target Frameworks is here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/schema/target-frameworks).

When working with the [Dependency section](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/schema/nuspec#dependencies), you may not need to use the group tag. Any users who encounter similar errors would do well to read through that section. They have samples of proper usage.